# gulp-sass includePaths failing to include vendor scss (possible ordering issue as well)

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have my application sass (in scss files) in various subdirectories within my *styles* directory, some of which `@extend` sass styles from various vendors which, (via bower) are in various subdirectories under the *vendor* directory.

Unfortunately the sass task fails to pick up those vendor scss files and any @extend declarations I have fail as they can't find the sass they're trying to extend from, e.g.

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    styles/censum/censum.scss
Error: ".graph-row" failed to @extend ".row".
       The selector ".row" was not found.
       Use "@extend .row !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
        on line 2 of styles/censum/censum.scss
```

My minimised example is as follows.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./styles/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSass({ includePaths: ['./vendor'] }).on('error', gulpSass.logError));
});
```

I also tried adding the vendor directories to gulp.src and not using includePaths, e.g.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src(['./vendor/**/*.scss', './styles/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(gulpSass().on('error', gulpSass.logError));
});
```

which does seem to reference the vendor files (as it drags everything in I guess), but I do get failures along the lines of:

```
Message:
    vendor/bower/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/sass/_bootstrap-datetimepicker.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$btn-primary-bg".
        on line 7 of vendor/bower/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/sass/_bootstrap-datetimepicker.scss
$bs-datetimepicker-active-bg: $btn-primary-bg !default;
```

which is possibly an ordering issue?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if includePaths doesn't recurse down subdirectories?  It seems to indicate that it does in the docs

Comment: Are you importing the vendor files or are you trying to directly extend them?

Comment: As it turns out the intent was to import some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm sharing is based on my understanding of your question.  I'll discuss it from the perspective of a new project, which seemed to work fine for me.

Let's assume we have a project called **sassy** and inside it is a **package.json** file created by running the following:

```
npm init -y
```

Then we are going to install Gulp and the SASS component like so:

```
npm install gulp gulp-sass -save-dev
```

Inside a **Gulpfile.js** at the root of our project we have the following code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp
    .src("./scss/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass({includePaths: ['./vendor']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});
```

As you can probably guess from the above code, we have a **vendor** directory and a **scss** directory at the root of our project.

Since I don't know what is in your **vendor** directory, I've populated mine with randomness.  Inside a **vendor/colors.scss** file I have the following:

```
.danger {
    color: red;
}

.light {
    color: silver;
}
```

I also have a nested file found at **vendor/sizing/article.scss** with the following code:

```
.title {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Now let's take a look at what is inside my **scss** directory.

I have a **scss/main.scss** file with two import statements like follows:

```
@import "./sidebar/navigation";
@import "./content/blog";
```

Again, all of this project is randomness.  I'm just trying to show the build process from all these files and directories.

I have two more SCSS files in my **scss** folder.  I have a file **scss/sidebar/navigation.scss** with the following code:

```
nav {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Finally I have a file with a bunch of imports and extends.  This file is **scss/content/blog.scss** and it contains the following:

```
@import "colors";
@import "sizing/article";

.title {
    @extend .danger;
    @extend .title;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Because the Gulp script is including the vendors directory, we can use relative paths for any of the files.  We import the two files from the **vendor** directory and then extend various classes where necessary.

Running `gulp sass` will build the CSS files in the project's **dist** directory.  Since I only used **scss/main.scss** for imports, it will contain all our styles.

Is this what you were trying to do?  If yes, run through everything I just shared and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Nic, this answer helped confirm the fix for me :-).  I replaced the `gulp.src('./styles/**/*.scss')` with `gulp.src('./styles/main.scss')` which contained the imports I wanted, that seems to have cleared the whole thing up (and I removed the includePath piece, no longer required it seems).

Answer (score 0):

IncludePaths takes a string array.

Try updating to the following.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./styles/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSass({ includePaths: ['./vendor'] }).on('error', gulpSass.logError));
});
```

See docs:

https://github.com/sass/node-sass#includepaths

Comment: Thanks for the spot!  I've fixed that issue but same problem occurs (I've updated my Q as well)